# Installation échouée : Le téléchargement a échoué. No working transports found

Tags: themes, errors, installation

i already have that extensions

**extension=php_openssl.dll**

and i add the other extension

**extension=php_curl.dll**

and i still get this error when i want to install a theme

> Installation échouée : Le téléchargement a échoué. No working
> transports found

Comment: you need to confirm that Curl can be used in your PHP and the extension is available and loaded, usually via phpinfo, it looks like WP has no way of downloading or making remote requests. Site health will also check for these things

Comment: i uncomment it . but nothing